# Parameter unaccessible when publishing dashboard to Tableau online

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dashboard that has worksheets using multiple different data sources which use a common parameter to filter across those datasources; this work fine.

When I come to publish the dashboard with the Parameter input into it, this work fine for myself since I'm an "editor", however the users having viewer or interactor permissions in Tableau Online are not seeing the parameter input.

Should I use a different way to filter date across multiple data source or is there a way to make that parameter input available to viewer and interactor ?

Comment: can you share the link ?